# Build.Reason showing IndividualCI other than PullRequest in azure devop

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to run different build steps when someone clicked enqueue button or when triggered by a PR merge. My yaml is fairly simple at the moment:

```
trigger:
- master
- R_Current_Sprint

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  demands:....
```

However, when I trigger it via a PR merge, we can see it showing reason as Individual CI.
[image]

For Build.Reason, the document says:

```
PullRequest: The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build.
```

So looks like my understanding is different here. I thought if I create a PR request and approve it, the build will be triggered with reason "PullRequest". Clearly my thought is wrong. So what is **"The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build"?**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That build wasn't for a pull request, it was for the *merge* that happened when the PR was completed. There's a difference; pull requests can require (via branch policy) builds to happen **before** they can be merged. That's the situation where you'll see the reason as Pull Request.

Comment: This seems to be the case. But what is the point to define so many varibles (e.g. pullrequest.source etc). As the PR hasn't been approved yet, we normally won't deploy to anywhere. So certainly won't need to do anything in the build pipeline other than it can be built.

Comment: That's *your* workflow. Many organizations **do** deploy as part of PRs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a misunderstanding about PR triggers. [Pull request (PR) triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) cause a pipeline to run whenever a pull request is opened with one of the specified target branches, or when changes are pushed to such a pull request.

In Azure Repos Git, this functionality is implemented using branch policies. To enable pull request validation in Azure Git Repos, navigate to the branch policies for the desired branch, and configure the [Build validation policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) (Validate code by pre-merging and building pull request changes) for that branch.